# ORA-00936 missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling

The following statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL_1,COL2) VALUES(SELECT MAX(COL_1) FROM TABLE1), 'XYZ');
```

throws the error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
 at the select clause. 
1. The table is empty for now.
2. COL_1 is a primary key intger field.
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: You have a little error. But your approach is not good one. If you do not have any value in col_1,.. you can not get any results by `SELECT MAX(COL_1) FROM TABLE1`... And if you have some value in col_1.. then you are always putting max value (a constant value) in first column.. Which does not seem to change by this approach.. What you want to achieve by the way?

Comment: I think you are trying to do something like insert max(id)+1.. Do you know about auto-inrement?

Answer (score 3):

Try as

```
    create table TABLE1 (COL_1 number, COL2 varchar2(5));

ALTER TABLE TABLE1
add CONSTRAINT t_pk PRIMARY KEY (col_1);

INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL_1,COL2) VALUES((SELECT nvl(MAX(COL_1),0) FROM TABLE1), 'XYZ');

INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL_1,COL2) VALUES((SELECT nvl(MAX(COL_1+1),0) FROM TABLE1), 'XYZ');
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/969d3/1)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the result of a query as a scalar expression, enclose the entire (sub)query in brackets, like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL_1,COL2) VALUES (
   (SELECT MAX(COL_1) FROM TABLE1),
  'XYZ'
);
```

On the other hand, you could simply use a [different syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm), here:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL_1,COL2)
SELECT MAX(COL_1), 'XYZ' 
FROM TABLE1
group by  'XYZ';
```

Comment: These two solutions have two very different outcomes.  The first inserts one row, the second inserts one row for every records ib TABLE1.

Comment: @APC: That's strange, there's no difference in SQL Server: [INSERT #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02f3e/1), [INSERT #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02f3e/2). I mean, I would never expect these two to be different in Oracle either. Anyway, the strangest part is that I [can't even test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14b0e/2) the second one in Oracle (i.e. in SQL Fiddle's Oracle, I don't have any other Oracle available.) It keeps telling me the command is not properly ended. There must be something I should know about `INSERT...SELECT` in Oracle that doesn't seem obvious enough (for me) from the manual.

Comment: Actually my comment was wrong.  The second solution *won't run* without a GROUP BY clause.  With the GROUP BY clause it will return one row.

Comment: I think there's a problem with SQL Fiddle.  The INSERT INTO ... SELECT syntax should work.

Answer (score 0):

remove one extra bracket

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL_1,COL2) SELECT MAX(COL_1) , 'XYZ' FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: You're right that the number of brackets must match, but alas you chose the wrong solution.